# Cayley's Theorem (Simple)

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I don't really like to ask questions where i don't understand whats going on at all, but i just can seem to wrap my head around Cayley's Theorem, we went over it in class and i also watched a YouTube lecture that had a proof of theorem in it. I can't quite wrap my head around it though.

A question in my textbook is as follows

Apply Cayley's Theorem to the group $U_{12}$. Write an explicit group
isomorphism from this group to a specic set of permutations of $U_{12}$.

Where $U_{12}$ is $\mathbb Z_{12}$ with all the stuff that does not have a multiplicative inverse thrown out.

Can someone Translate what this says to English and then perhaps back to math in a simpler way perhaps?

Comment: Dear Faust7: No need to qualify your question titles with the add-on (Simple). And don't worry about asking questions when you don't understand much of what's being asked, or about a particular theorem you don't quite understand. That's what questions are for. How "simple" a question may seem is in the "eye of the beholder". And it's not an easy task formulating a question when one feels lost. From your posts earlier: You clearly provide any ideas you have, you articulate what you're not clear about, you are pretty clear about your questions. That's all we hope for!

Comment: Haha thank you for the advice, i just feel that this site isn't really where an undergrad should be asking questions when i look through most of what other people are asking questions about. Thank you =)

Comment: Believe me, Faust7, we get MANY questions that are at a far lower level than yours! We welcome "ALL levels of mathematical questions." Some of us are prone to notice how much others seem to know, and gloss over (deprecate) what we ourselves know. Others tend to think they know it all. I don't know about you, but I'm in the former camp, not in the latter! ;-)

Comment: Wow thanks guys its alot to digest but between Roberts and anons answer you guys made that much easier to understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do the whole exercise step-by-step as illustration, but for $U(8)$ instead.

1. Find the elements of $U(8)=({\bf Z}/8{\bf Z})^\times$: $\{1,3,5,7\}$ (technically, their equivalence classes).
2. For each element in $a\in U(8)$, check what left-translation* does to the group's elements: $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline a & x & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ \hline 1 & 1\cdot x & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ \hline 3 & 3\cdot x & 3 & 1 & 7 & 5 \\ \hline 5 & 5\cdot x & 5 & 7 & 1 & 3 \\ \hline 7 & 7\cdot x & 7 & 5 & 3 & 1 \\ \hline \end{array}$$
3. Let $\psi:U(8)\to {\rm Sym}(U(8))$ be our desired homomorphism from $U(8)$ into the group of set-theoretic permutations of the elements of $U(8)$. Then for each $a\in U(8)$, $\psi(a)\in {\rm Sym}$ is the permutation $x\mapsto ax$. Explicitly, for example, in [two-line notation](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Two-line_notation_for_permutations), $$\psi(5)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ 5 & 7 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix},$$ simply by reading off the second-to-last row in the table I made.

Of course, whatever notation and level of explicitness the author expects of you is your duty to find out yourself, but this is the idea.

*By left translation we mean the map $x\mapsto ax$ under the group operation. In an abelian group, left and right translation are in fact the same.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the group $U_{12}$ which has $\phi(12)=4$ elements. Lets call them 
$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. You know the four elements, you'll need to write them explicitly.

Now Cayley theorem says that each one of the four elements defines a permutation:

$$f_i(x_j)=x_ix_j \,.$$

The problem asks you to explicitly write out the four elements, and calculate the four functions...

Answer (score 1):

A group is essentially a collection of invertible transformations you can do on something. Each element is a transformation, and the group law is composition. Cayley's theorem is basically what rigorously justifies this idea: groups can be seen as a collection of ways of shuffling objects around, which means they should act like a subgroup of some symmetric group (i.e. fundamentally all groups are just permuting things). So they want you to note a couple things:

-$U_{12}$ is isomorphic to some permutation group

-Each element of $U_{12}$ is then a way of shuffling objects around.

-this means that you can look at multiplication in $U_{12}$ as a way of shuffling its own elements around! So it should match up with a subgroup of the permutation group on $4$ elements.

As an example: for any $g\in U_{12}$, $1g=g$. So $1$ represents the identity permutation. For others you may need to be more explicit: $11\cdot 1=11,\ \ 11\cdot 5=7,\ \ 11\cdot 7=5,\ \ 11\cdot 11=1$. So $11$ interchanges the pairs $(1,11)$ and $(5,7)$. That can be viewed as an element in a permutation group as well. The idea is to find a specific subgroup of the permutation group that captures the behaviour of $U_{12}$ in this way, by matching each element of $U_{12}$ with a certain type of permutation.

Overall goal: match each element of $U_{12}$ to an element in the permutation group on four elements, in such a way that this permutation subgroup has the same group structure as $U_{12}$.